# how to pop max of the list based on customized key python

Tags: python, list, max

I have a list of string: `["abc", "a", "abcdef", "g", "h"]`. I am trying to pop the max of the list based on customized key. In this case, my customized key is the length of the item in the list:
`Input: ["abc", "a", "abcdef", "g", "h"]`
`Output: "abcdef", 6` where customized key is the `len`. Also, the list will be without max item: `["abc", "a", "g", "h"]`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you post some code with your attempt to do it?  E.g. using Python's built-in `max` function.

Comment: What should happen if two strings have the same max length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> strings = ["abc", "a", "abcdef", "g", "h"]
>>> strings.remove(max(strings, key=len))
>>> strings
['abc', 'a', 'g', 'h']
>>> def pop_max(iterable, key=lambda x: x):
...     m = max(iterable, key=key)
...     iterable.remove(m)
...     return m, key(m)
...
>>> pop_max(["abc", "a", "abcdef", "g", "h"])
('h', 'h')
>>> pop_max(["abc", "a", "abcdef", "g", "h"], key=len)
('abcdef', 6)
```

Comment: The question refers to "popping" the value so it might be better to break the ```remove``` line in two so the removed value can be saved.

Comment: @sj95126 Yes, also says `Output: "abcdef", 6`.